# Subtracting items in the same column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with a dataset that contains some data that looks like this. The names are indicative of one being the superset of the other and hence my requirement is to subtract the subset from the superset.

My table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiPbV.png)

My expected output is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxhii.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a self-join joining on part of the join key using either a regular expression (as below), or something like `SUBSTRING` `REPLACE` to join ABC to ABC_1

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    UNNEST([
      STRUCT('ABC' AS col_name, 100 AS col_value),
      STRUCT('DEF' AS col_name, 50 AS col_value),
      STRUCT('ABC_1' AS col_name, 20 AS col_value),
      STRUCT('DEF_1' AS col_name, 5 AS col_value)
    ])
)

SELECT
  base.col_name,
  base.col_value,
  subtract.col_value AS subtract_value,
  base.col_value - COALESCE(subtract.col_value, 0) AS diff
FROM test_data AS base
LEFT JOIN test_data AS subtract
-- Join on anything left of the underscore
ON base.col_name = REGEXP_EXTRACT(subtract.col_name, r'^([^_]+)_')
-- Exclude any col_name that has an underscore from the base rows
WHERE base.col_name NOT LIKE '%\\_%'
```